# What book contains this antlered humanoid fey?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, product-identification

In one of the later Monster Manuals, there was a Fey called something like "Master of the Forest"  It took the form of a human male with antlers.  Can anyone confirm or correct the name and tell me exactly which book it was in?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## It may be the verdant prince

He's found in the *Monster Manual IV* on pp. 172-3. Here's the illustration.
[image: prince]

He's a CR 11 fey with 16 Hit Dice. If you want to play one, he has a Level Adjustment of +4, making his ECL 20.